# Devise.bcrypt is generating a different value in my specs vs in my fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I am creating a customer in my fixtures, and setting its `encrypted_password` to `Devise.bcrypt(User, 'password')`. Then in my specs I am trying to login with the password 'password' but am being told that the password is invalid.

So I tried running `Devise.bcrypt(User, 'password')` in my specs and comparing it to the value stored in the database for that customer, and the values were different. Am I doing something wrong here? When I load the fixtures and then log in with that email/password in the actual application is logs in just fine.

Here is my fixture:

```
larry_sellers:
  first_name: Larry
  last_name: Sellers
  email: LarrySellers@fakemail.com
  phone: 123456789
  marketing_emails: false
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise.bcrypt(User, 'password') %>
  type: Customer
```

Here is what I ran in my specs to check the values of both passwords:

```
throw Exception.new "DB: #{Customer.first.encrypted_password} \n DEVISE: #{Devise.bcrypt(User, 'password')}"
```

Comment: In 3.5.1, "Devise.bcrypt is deprecated; use Devise::Encryptor.digest instead". Not sure it'll make a difference, but can't hurt to use it. Because indeed, `Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatable#password_digest` calls `Devise::Encryptor.digest(self.class, password)`

Comment: Is the number of stretches being changed at some point?